# Inheritance and Casting design

Tags: java, design-patterns, casting

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
interface Transport { ... }

class Car      implements Transport {}
class Bicycle  implements Transport {}
class Airplane implements Transport {}
```

Each of the classes implement some specific methods.

In some part of an EJB code, there is an service that gets `Transport` instances from a database, and it call the methods specific to `Car`.

```
Transport transport = getTransport(...);
Car car = (Car) transport;
car.specificCarMethod(...);
```

Is there any good practice to avoid the Cast?

Comment: You can use a generic method. Something lice `<T> T getTransport(Class<T> clazz, ...);`

Comment: Sorry , can you be more specific ?

Comment: Encapsulating the type cast is not avoiding it.

Answer (score 2):

That is rather opinion based; here is my opinion.

If the interface is carefully designed, you shouldn't need to do a cast. You may need to publish specificCarMethod in the interface, and implement it with an empty body in all classes except Car.

As of Java 8, you can specify a default implementation for a method, prior to Java 8, you would use an abstract class in place of or in addition to the interface.

You may also consider using the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) if you want to separate the code from the classes implementing the interface, and avoid declaring some methods in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact use case, I would use composition/aggregation instead of inheritance.

```
interface Transport {}

interface Car extends Transport {}

// decorates a transport instance.
class CarImpl implements Car {

  CarImpl(final Transport transport) {
    // do stuff and decorate the instance.
  }
}
```

You create a CarImpl based on a transport. This way you can use a `Car` when you need a car. But without knowing the concrete use case this is just a different approach ...